# Configurable swatches Not working Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-swatches

Configurable swatches Not working on product page it is not selection.

[image]

Comment: did you upgrade the Magento version?

Comment: If i can upgrate the version.so it will be solve it.??

Comment: Please check your console, if there any js missing than copy the JS file from base to your custom theme.

Comment: was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: share your URL..I can look and suggest you

Comment: http://softtest.bh-55.webhostbox.net/demo/index.php/green-saree.html

Comment: That is the url please check the color and size .it is not selecting

Comment: I have posted an answer, please look

Answer (score 0):

Your actual issue is

> TypeError: Product.ConfigurableSwatches is not a constructor

You can try two things:

1. Check the Configurable swatches with default theme
2. apply the changes as mentioned in below post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845427/typeerror-product-configurableswatches-is-not-a-constructor-in-magento-1-9-3

Answer (score 0):

I can see error in your console,

To resolve this issue you can do following.

1) Open this file: app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/configurable/swatch-js.phtml

2) Instead this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
        var swatchesConfig = new Product.ConfigurableSwatches(spConfig);
    });
</script>
```

do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
        if (Product.ConfigurableSwatches) { //put this Extra validation
            var swatchesConfig = new Product.ConfigurableSwatches(spConfig);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, i have try that but my problem not solved ..problem is (option-yellow is-media)

Comment: Correct hover showing (option-yellow is-media hover) but my code not showing hover ..